# How to check if an IP Address is in any of the networks in a list of networks in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

So, for singular search:

```
from netaddr import IPAddress, IPNetwork
if IPAddress( address ) in IPNetwork( network ):
    print( 'in' )
```

But what if you're given a list of networks?  Is it possible to do it without using a for loop?  What is a pythonic way to do this task? ...preferably readable, then faster.

```
from netaddr import IPAddress, IPNetwork
networks = [
    '1.0.0.0\8',
    '2.0.0.0\8',
    # ...
    '21.22.14.0\24' # something random
]

for network in networks:
    if IPAddress( address ) in IPNetwork( network ):
        print( 'in' )
        break
```

EDIT: For anyone interested, I took my given list of networks, and expanded each network to its list of addresses.  Then I took that list of addresses and made a set from it.  Given that sets have O(1) lookup, I figured it would help.

The time it took to complete with the for loop ( no set ) was 24 minutes.
The time it took to use:

```
address_set = set()

for network in networks:
    for address in IPNetwork( network ).subnet( 32 ):
        non_CIDR_address = str( address ).split( '/' )[ 0 ]
        address_set.add( non_CIDR_address )

if query_address in address_set:
    print( 'in' )
if address in address_set:
    print( 'in' )
```

...was 2 minutes and 37 seconds.

GO SETS!

**BEWARE**: expanding the networks can be memory expensive.

Comment: Unless `netaddr` has some kind of "set of discontinguous networks" class, this seems like the obvious, Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: You could of course write your own set of discontiguous networks class, and if you're going to do this 1000 times it might be a good idea… but ultimately its `__contains__` method is going to have the same loop in it.

Comment: I guess you could do some clever stuff, like if you have `1.0.0.0/8`, '2.0.0.0/8`, `3.0.0.0/8`, you could store that as `0.0.0.0/10 - 0.0.0.0/8` and collapse 4 checks into 2, but I wouldn't write that unless this was a performance bottleneck or something, because I can't imagine the end result would be easier to understand.

Comment: @abarnert: I think that you're right that I have to manipulate the data before I do this search, thanks.  

I think maybe I'll expand each network into its individual addresses, and make a super large set for easy look up then

Comment: Expanding each network into its individual addresses may mean a set of up to 2^32 elements. Is that actually acceptable for your use case? (Even if it is, what happens when you expand to include IPv6?)

Comment: I guess we'll see; luckily, at any point in time, the list of networks isn't greater than maybe 50?  Still, that's 50 * 2 ^ 32 in the worst case huh?

Comment: The advantage of using an explicit set is that you could just union the 50 sets into one (so you only need one set lookup, not 50), so it's still 2^32. And that just gave me a thought: you might want to look and see if any of the interval-set/range-set libraries on PyPI or elsewhere can handle this. An interval-set is basically just a sparse set represented as a discontiguous set of ranges over the domain, which is exactly what your networks are. They should be able to merge adjacent sets, etc. automatically, and possibly even convert to a dense set representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if any(IPAddress(address) in IPNetwork(network) for network in networks):
   ...
```

Optimization can be done by only instantiating the `IPAddress` once, and by storing `IPNetwork`s in the list.

Comment: doesn't that still use a for loop?

Comment: This is still effectively using a `for` loop. It may be more readable and a few % faster, but it's basically the same algorithm.

Comment: @user2738698: It uses a genex, which has the "for" keyword, but it is not an explicit `for` loop. **Something** must loop; you can't get around that.

Comment: I see, well, the optimizations certainly improves performance, thanks; but there's no escaping the for loop, huh?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It is an explicit `for` loop by most reasonable standards. It's explicitly using the `for` keyword. It has the same semantics. It compiles to a bytecode `FOR_ITER` loop, etc. It's not a `for` _statement_, but that just means it's a different explicit `for` loop syntax than a `for` statement is.

Answer (score 0):

(None of this is specific to Python, so in case this question really is about syntax and coding style, this answer contributes nothing to that. Basically, it expands a little on what I think abarnert was suggesting in comments.)

Here's something that does not require looping over all ranges at the cost of making a basic assumption and constructing a search tree: assuming the ranges you want to check are non-overlapping (i.e. no two ranges contain some shared IP), you can construct a search tree for your ranges, and then search for the IP (or even ranges) in `O(log n)` in your ordered set of ranges once you adjust the search function of the tree suitably, which is pretty straightforward.

In case you have overlapping ranges, you may want to have a look at interval trees, which you should be able to apply to that case pretty easily.

Both will only be useful if you want to query lots of times with a nontrivial number of networks to maintain. If you actually only have to handle 50 networks at any time, that should be trivial and work within an instant with the list thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things [`netaddr`'s](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) [`IPSet`](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.IPSet) is useful for.

It provides a nice API and it's implemented to be reasonably optimal (checking if an address belongs to it will *not* result in a linear scan of all member networks).

```py
from netaddr import IPSet
networks = [
    '1.0.0.0/8',
    '2.0.0.0/8',
    # ...
    '21.22.14.0/24' # something random
]
address = '123.123.123.123'
ip_set = IPSet(networks)  # Potentially expensive time-wise, relatively speaking
print(address in ip_set)  # Reasonably fast *and* readable
```

Depending on the number of the networks and their relationships (overlapping or not) it's likely you'll want to construct `IPSet(networks)` once and reuse it, as creating it may be relatively expensive. You'll have to time that with your data.